TCL is there a way to pattern match a line within while gets statement?
This TCL is supposed to parse a file until it finds a pattern. Then there will be a variable number of some sort of preamble lines that have a different distinct pattern that I want to skip and then do interesting stuff with the lines coming next. So once the pattern is matched I need to eat away the preamble lines. I know a pattern in these lines but not how many there are. Could be zero to N.
Looking for a way if there is a pattern check possible inside the while gets condition.
Something like (pseudo TCL code):
set fp [ open $fname ]
while { [gets $fp line] >= 0 } {
    if {[regexp $pat $line]} {
        while { [gets $fp line] == some preamble } { skip }
        Now do something with $line
    ...
    }
} 
close $fp

That while can be broken up into multiple lines. But is there a one line solution?

I'm not aware of anything specifically for that purpose. The problem is you need a little state machine to say when lines are "interesting" and that sort of thing tends to be very format-specific.
You can write a helper procedure though.
proc forEachInterestingLine {lineVar channel body} {
    upvar 1 $lineVar var
    set interesting 0
    while {[gets $channel var] >= 0} {
        if {!$interesting} {
            set interesting [regexp START_INTERESTING $var]
        }
        if {$interesting} {
            uplevel 1 $body
            set interesting [expr {![regexp END_INTERESTING $var]}]
        }
    }
}

set ch [open thefile.txt]
forEachInterestingLine line $ch {
    # do something here
    puts $line
}
close $ch

You'll need to define what marks the beginning and end of an interesting section (and the order of tests gets a bit different if you want to exclude the start and end markers from interesting-ness).
